# I want to solve this without changing a column name in the database table. Is there any way to solve this?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notices.notice_category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `notices` where `notices`.`notice_category_id` = 1 and `notices`.`notice_category_id` is not null and `notices`.`deleted_at` is null)

```
This is notices table migration
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();          
            $table->text('subject');
            $table->integer('category_id');           
            $table->date('date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
notice category table

 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notice_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
model for noitceCategory
  public function notices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Notice::class);
    }
```

```
notice model
 public function noticeCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(NoticeCategory::class);
    }
```

And I am trying to count using following code

```
$noticecategory->notices->count();

``
tell me if any other information are required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `NoticeCategory` model define foreign key for notice table

```
public function notices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Notice::class,'category_id');
}
```

If you don't provide foreign key argument then laravel assumes that the model_name_id will be the foreign key for that relation

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, you saved me, I need to learn more about laravel.